# Automatically grab iOS GPS data for Orbeon form?

Tags: ios, orbeon

I'm a bit new to Orbeon and I'm trying to fogure how to populate some form data automatically.  For instance, how does one grab the lat/lon information from an iOS form viewer, with permission of course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbeon doen't have this capability built-in. But if you can do it with JavaScript, you could then store it into a hidden input using the [JavaScript API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-integration).